# Move all files except one

Tags: linux, bash, glob

How can I move all files except one? I am looking for something like:

```
'mv ~/Linux/Old/!Tux.png ~/Linux/New/'
```

where I move old stuff to new stuff -folder except `Tux.png`. !-sign represents a negation. Is there some tool for the job?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Put the following to your .bashrc

```
shopt -s extglob
```

It extends regexes.
You can then move all files except one by

```
mv !(fileOne) ~/path/newFolder
```

### Exceptions in relation to other commands

Note that, in copying directories, the forward-flash cannot be used in the name as noticed in the thread [Why extglob except breaking except condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597198/54964):

```
cp -r !(Backups.backupdb) /home/masi/Documents/
```

so `Backups.backupdb/` is wrong here before the negation and I would not use it neither in moving directories because of the risk of using wrongly then globs with other commands and possible other exceptions.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Mine was flat out wrong; luckily I had used it in a folder with only few files. Here is more information about the method Masi shows: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern Go to "Extended pattern language" and you will find more info on this. Thanks to @paul-whittaker for pointing at the issue.

Comment: This is an old answer but it's still valid. I'm using Ubuntu 18 and extglob seems to be enabled by default (I didn't shopt it). I used the following command to move all files in the current directory into an archive that is also within this directory, NOT including any other archive folders:    
`mv !(arc*) archive_190629b`

Answer (score 178):

If you use bash and have the `extglob` shell option set (which is usually the case):

```
mv ~/Linux/Old/!(Tux.png) ~/Linux/New/
```

Comment: I got something wrong when I tested the command for many items:
mv ~/Linux/Old/!(Tux.png Tux1.png Tux2.png) ~/Linux/New/ 

It empties the whole Old -directory. What is wrong?

Comment: @UnixBasics, try: ~/Linux/Old/!(Tux.png|Tux1.png|Tux2.png)

Comment: @Juliano Very cool command! Are there more mathematical operations like OR and XOR? I assume a pipe is for AND.

Comment: @UnixBasis, yes. Take a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html

Comment: @Juliano I am rather confused of the patterns like: 
mv ~/Linux/?(Tux*.png) ~/Linux/New/
mv ~/Linux/+(Tux*.png) ~/Linux/New/
In the former, I wanted to move 0-1 Tux -photo. In the latter, I wanted move 1-n Tux photos. They moved everyhing. Why? Is it possible to move a specific amount of photos?

Comment: A specific amount? No AFAIK. You must be more clear at which files you have and which ones you want to move, otherwise it is difficult to say what command you have to type. Note that these patterns are regular expressions, they are executed over each filename, not the other way around.

Comment: Such a configuration (extglob) or an equivalent seems to be default for Mac Terminal with "command line tools" installed, as this syntax worked perfectly.

Comment: For ZSH user, instead of using `shopt` (which will give `command not found` error), add this to your `.zshrc`: 

`setopt extended_glob` then the [syntax for glob](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) will also change accordingly.

Thus use `mv ~/path/to/source^(exception) ~/path/to/target/folder` should do

Answer (score 80):

I would go with the traditional find & xargs way:

```
find ~/Linux/Old -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name Tux.png -print0 | 
    xargs -0 mv -t ~/Linux/New
```

`-maxdepth 1` makes it not search recursively. If you only care about files, you can say `-type f`. `-mindepth 1` makes it not include the `~/Linux/Old` path itself into the result. Works with any filenames, including with those that contain embedded newlines.

One comment notes that the mv `-t` option is a probably GNU extension. For systems that don't have it

```
find ~/Linux/Old -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name Tux.png \
    -exec mv '{}' ~/Linux/New \;
```

Comment: Upvoted since it encourages learning a powerful tool, find. Note, for files with whitespace this wont' work. Consider "find -print0 | xargs -0" or else forego xargs: "find [what you said] -exec mv -t {} ~/Linux/New \;"

Comment: If your mv command doesn't have the -t option, then either use "find ... -exec mv {} Linux/New \;" or "find ... | xargs -I {} mv {} Linux/New". The -t option seems to be a GNU extension, which is fine for Linux, but probably not elsewhere.

Comment: jhs, oh i fail. i somehow thought xargs splitted at newlines but not at spaces. looks like i confused it with "read" :) ill fix it

Comment: Great thanks for the awesome tip! I was going to choose sth because it targets the question. However, I can sense the usefulness of your commands later on, so I must choose "find and xargs" way. It just rocks. Thanks :)

Comment: Way to complicated. Masi answer is more complete, easier and therefor more correct

Comment: @user637338 all of your measures are subjective, except "correct". To conclude the objective from subjectives doesn't seem correct either. My take on level of complication: `find` should be your daily bread and butter on linux, and then my `find` line reads almost like natural language.

Comment: I just wanted to give justification why I rated your answer down and Masi's up. Simplicity even in nature should be one of the indicators for good solutions. I think this we can agree on. The question then remains, what simplicity means for different types of people. Comparing your answer with this: "mv !(fileOne) ~/path/newFolder", I would say this in terms of simplicity wins. This is what I wanted to state, maybe that was not clear.

Comment: @user637338 I think the comparison is unfair :) It should be compared with "shopt -s extglob; mv !(fileOne) ~/path/newFolder"

Comment: No it is not unfair as you have to enable this once and then you are able to use a nice and short command. The command in this answer is always as long, maybe beautiful to some, but none the less always long.

Comment: Be very careful with the FROM parameter (1st parameter) of this command.  If you set it to the root of your system, you will be screwed.  You will move all your files - flattening their structure, and wrecking your existing folder structure, with no simple way to restore.

Answer (score 37):

A quick way would be to modify the tux filename so that your move command will not match.

For example:

```
mv Tux.png .Tux.png

mv * ~/somefolder

mv .Tux.png Tux.png
```

Comment: don't use "*.*", as that will only move files that have a "." in the name. Just "*" is enough.

Comment: If you change it to * it will remove your renamed file as well.

Comment: @John T: No, the * glob doesn't match files that begin with dot.

Answer (score 37):

I think the easiest way to do is with backticks

```
mv `ls -1 ~/Linux/Old/ | grep -v Tux.png` ~/Linux/New/
```

Edit:

Use backslash with ls instead to prevent using it with alias, i.e. mostly ls is aliased as ls --color.

```
mv `\ls -1 ~/Linux/Old/ | grep -v Tux.png` ~/Linux/New/
```

Thanks @Arnold Roa

Comment: Can you please explain why you use `grep -v` there?

Comment: -v option in grep excludes the result, it's like take everything except Tux.png

Comment: This is certainly intuitive, but answers above are better. If you're writing a script, for example, this would require you to be in the correct directory..

Comment: @nJGL We can also give absolute path here, I used homedirectory (~) since question had this

Comment: @RohailAbbas Fair enough. ✌️

Answer (score 18):

For bash, [sth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670460/move-all-files-except-one/670475#670475) is correct. Here is the [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) (my shell of choice) syntax:

```
mv ~/Linux/Old/^Tux.png ~/Linux/New/
```

Requires `EXTENDED_GLOB` shell option to be set.

Comment: What if we want to exclude two files?

Answer (score 16):

I find this to be a bit safer and easier to rely on for simple moves that exclude certain files or directories.

```
ls -1 | grep -v ^$EXCLUDE | xargs -I{} mv {} $TARGET
```

Comment: This is the best solution for Busybox / ASH

Comment: This worked for me in situation where I had to move all files except few folders to another directory

Comment: The `-l` option to `ls` will include a lot of irrelevant info on the command line and result in failure of mv command.

Comment: @jdhao It's not an L it's a 1.

Comment: Works even on the simplest Docker containers

Comment: This is the safest for my case I think.

Answer (score 8):

This could be simpler and easy to remember and it works for me.

`mv $(ls ~/folder | grep -v ~/folder/exclude.png) ~/destination`

Comment: Very useful. `-v` means `--invert-match ` I think for multiple terms it may be possible to use `grep -e` but have not yet worked out how.

Comment: I tried to generalise this for a longer list in the `grep -v` section and it became very complicated and had to ask for help. Interesting and useful solution however https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/708296/detailed-bash-script-with-cp-and-grep-will-not-work-with-spaces-in-filenames

Answer (score 6):

The following is not a 100% guaranteed method, and should not at all be attempted for scripting. But some times it is good enough for quick interactive shell usage. A file file glob like

```
[abc]*
```

(which will match all files with names starting with a, b or c) can be negated by inserting a "^" character first, i.e.

```
[^abc]*
```

I sometimes use this for not matching the "lost+found" directory, like for instance:

```
mv /mnt/usbdisk/[^l]* /home/user/stuff/.
```

Of course if there are other files starting with l I have to process those afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

This can bei done without `grep` like this:

```
ls ~/Linux/Old/ -QI Tux.png | xargs -I{} mv ~/Linux/Old/{} ~/Linux/New/
```

Note: `-I` is a captial i and makes the `ls` command ignore the Tux.png file, which is listed afterwards.

The output of `ls` is then piped into `mv` via `xargs`, which allows to use the  output of ls as source argument for mv.

`ls -Q` just quotes the filenames listed by ls.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain what you posted please?

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
mv $(echo * | sed s:Tux.png::g) ~/Linux/New/
```

You have to be in the folder though.

Answer (score 4):

```
mv `find Linux/Old '!' -type d | fgrep -v Tux.png` Linux/New
```

The find command lists all regular files and the fgrep command filters out any Tux.png.  The backticks tell mv to move the resulting file list.

Comment: Never, ever, evaluate find as arguments for another command. Bad things will happen. You may have just created a vulnerability. Always use the find -print0 | xargs -0 construct, or find -exec.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls ~/Linux/Old/ | grep -v Tux.png | xargs -i {} mv ~/Linux/New/'
```

Comment: This command seems missing one part and doesn't work in my computer.
`ls ~/Linux/Old/ | grep -v Tux.png | xargs -I{} mv {} ~/Linux/New/` works instead.

Answer (score 0):

move all files(not include except file) to except_file
`find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name except_file -print0 |xargs -0 mv -t ./except_file`
for example(cache is current except file)
`find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name cache -print0 |xargs -0 mv -t ./cache`