# how to move all files in the same directory except one into that one in UNIX ssh

Tags: unix, ssh, mv

how to move all files in the same directory except one into that one in UNIX ssh?

for example. having backup directory and moving all other files into backup

thanks in advance

Comment: Selecting all files except one in Unix:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670460/move-all-files-except-one

Comment: `scp` is what you want. Type `man scp` for more information.

Comment: i get an error in my shell. Manual entry for scp not found or not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rsync` is one of the possibility

```
rsync -av from/ to/ --exclude=file_to_exclude
```

More information about the `rsync` command:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rsync.htm

Comment: I get an error that 'Manual entry for `rsync` not found or not installed.
'