# Concatenate all files except one calling system - Python

Tags: python, bash, unix, system

To concatenate all the TXT files of a folder, it can be done with cat easily:

```
cat ./tmp*.txt >./tmp/all.txt
```

However, I want to concatenate all files except one which can be done with the following command as explained similarly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670460/move-all-files-except-one):

```
cat ./tmp/!(1.txt) >./tmp/all_except_1.txt
```

These commands work perfectly on the command line, but I am trying to call them from python with `os.system` command and gives an error

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('cat ./tmp/!(1.txt) >./tmp/all_except_1.txt')
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Does someone know why and how can be solved?

Comment: `os.system` runs the Bourne or POSIX shell: `sh`.  What you are trying is `bash` specific.  You will have to prefix your command with  `bash -c ` (untested).  Where are you doing your `shopt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable Extended Pattern Matching in bash before call it:

```
os.system("bash -O extglob -c 'cat ./tmp/!(1.txt) >./tmp/all_except_1.txt'")
```

Comment: I read in a post that the problem could be related with bash, but I didn't know about that option. Thank you, it works perfectly!