# How to merge 2 LOCAL git repositories on 2 machines into one?

Tags: git, merge, repository

I have been developing 2 parts of a project separately, and I'd like to merge them. I did not push any of them to a remote server, but I want to.

2 local repos to merge :

- software on Linux PC (SW)
- microcontroller firmware on Windows PC (FW)

How do I end up with a single repository with this structure ?

```
project
|
+----fw
|
+----sw
```

And if possible, keep the history of SW and FW ?

[This article](http://julipedia.meroh.net/2014/02/how-to-merge-multiple-git-repositories.html) explains a similar situation. But I wonder if I could do the same, setting up only one remote, like :

1. push SW to remote from Linux
2. clone SW from Windows into a new directory
3. create a branch called merge-fw
4. pull FW from local directory → **what's the syntax
   for the *repository* argument in [git-pull](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) ???**
5. merge merge-fw into master

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the Windows repo shall become the master repo for a moment.

#### On the Linux repo

Ensure all your sources are located under a `sw` directory, if needed [move files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670460/520162) and `git commit` these changes. Create a new branch `merge-to-windows`:

```
    mkdir sw
    mv !(sw) sw # needs extglob set (shopt -s extglob)
    git add . && git commit -m "move all sources to sw"
    git checkout -b merge-to-windows
```

#### On the Windows repo

1. Ensure all your sources are located under a `fw` directory, if needed move files and `git commit` these changes
2. Add a new remote to the Windows repo pointing to your Linux repo

   ```
   git remote add linux <path to your linux machine>
   ```
3. Fetch the current state of your Linux repo with

   ```
   git fetch linux
   ```
4. Merge the `merge-to-windows` branch of your linux repo

   ```
   git merge linux/merge-to-windows
   ```
5. Now your `master` branch on Windows holds the history of `sw` and `fw`. We can push this state back to the `master` branch on Linux

   ```
   git push linux master:master
   ```

**Done**

Comment: Great, I worked ! Although a little off topic, this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596260/git-remote-add-with-other-ssh-port#3596272) on _git remote add_ syntax may help noobs like me.