# How to turn a git repository into a subdirectory of a new repo?

Tags: git, directory, subdirectory

It turns out a git repo I created betters suits as subdirectory, say `module x`, of a more general repository. How can I copy the original history (no signed commits) over such that now all the paths have the prefix `module x\`?

I could of course simply make moving everything into that subdirectory a new commit, but I'd prefer a solution that makes history look as if the former repo was always in the subdirectory.

---

I tried `git subtree add --prefix="module x" ../module_x master` from a temporary parallel folder with a fresh repository (since otherwise `git subtree` complains about the already existing prefix), but end up with

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Working tree has modifications.  Cannot add.
```

This seems to be due to the lack of an initial commit, because if I

```
touch .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m"Init"
```

it works, but I end up with the original history in a separate branch plus a commit of moving, so just the manual solution I mentioned before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir -p module_x; mv all the files and* module_x/' HEAD
```

Did the trick. I'm using msysgit, but I guess in Linux [`shopt -s extglob; mv !(module_x) module_x/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/789029/321973) should work even better...

If the files explicitly mentioned have not existed through the entire history, you may have to trick a bit and append `; true` to the `--tree-filter` such that `mv`'s non-zero exit code is ignored.