# Move all files except specified folder

Tags: linux, shell, mv

Im trying to move all the contents of the current directory to a new folder in the current directory using a script

`mv !\(.svn\|$line\|.\|..\) $line`

error is

`mv: cannot stat '!(.svn|RSSIFXServicesCommon|.|..)': No such file or directory`

I echoed the command to output and if i copy and execute the command myself, it works.

I tried enabling extglob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move all files except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670460/move-all-files-except-one)

Answer (score 1):

With extended regex (`shopt -s extglob`), there's no need to quote your regex:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/t/4
touch /tmp/t/{1,2,3}
shopt -s extglob
cd /tmp/t
mv !(4|.|..) 4
```

This also works if I put this in a shell script.

Comment: `mv: cannot stat '!(4|.|..)': No such file or directory`

Comment: Which shell is that?

Comment: its bash but its running on a MingW64

Comment: That doesn't sound like the bash version(s) I've around here. If extglob doesn't work, bash should interpret the '!' as history expansion and you should get an [event not found](https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found) message (unless your bash even has history expansion disabled?).

Comment: if the extglob is unset, it is interpreting the "!" as previous event just like you said. But i have set the extglob and when I run the command `mv !(4|.|..) 4` it is giving the following error `mv: cannot stat '!(4|.|..)': No such file or directory`